# UITextField becomeFirstResponder crashes the iOS app randomly

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitextfield, twitter-fabric

I developed an app which had multiple text fields with the glow border for the text field. It has been working fine when I do an internal testing, but I see the Fabric is reporting the crash with the following stacktrace. Am I missing something to trace this issue? Can anybody give some light on this issue?

```
Thread : Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException
0  CoreFoundation                 0x185de0f48 __exceptionPreprocess
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x19a92ff80 objc_exception_throw
2  CoreFoundation                 0x185de0e90 -[NSException initWithCoder:]
3  Foundation                     0x186c85fb4 -[NSISEngine minimizeConstantInObjectiveRowWithHead:]
4  Foundation                     0x186c85aa8 -[NSISEngine optimize]
5  Foundation                     0x186c815dc -[NSISEngine withBehaviors:performModifications:]
6  UIKit                          0x18b36e1d4 -[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:]
7  UIKit                          0x18b680834 __UIViewWasRemovedFromSuperview
8  UIKit                          0x18b36cbf8 -[UIView(Hierarchy) removeFromSuperview]
9  UIKit                          0x18b895e58 -[UIKeyboardPredictionView setPredictionViewState:animate:notify:]
10 UIKit                          0x18b77f41c -[UIKeyboardImpl updatePredictionView]
11 UIKit                          0x18b486c68 -[UIKeyboardImpl finishLayoutChangeWithArguments:]
12 UIKit                          0x18b39ce8c -[UIKeyboardImpl updateLayout]
13 UIKit                          0x18b3a1bd4 -[UIKeyboardImpl setDelegate:force:]
14 UIKit                          0x18b39b0b8 -[UIPeripheralHost(UIKitInternal) _reloadInputViewsForResponder:]
15 UIKit                          0x18b39abec -[UIResponder(UIResponderInputViewAdditions) reloadInputViews]
16 UIKit                          0x18b3fc09c -[UIResponder becomeFirstResponder]
17 UIKit                          0x18b3fc448 -[UIView(Hierarchy) becomeFirstResponder]
18 UIKit                          0x18b483814 -[UITextField becomeFirstResponder]
19 MyApp                          0x10012f6a4 -[FormattedField becomeFirstResponder] (GlowingTextField.m:139)
20 MyApp                          0x100130190 -[GlowingTextField becomeFirstResponder] (GlowingTextField.m:271)
21 UIKit                          0x18b5341a8 -[UITextInteractionAssistant(UITextInteractionAssistant_Internal) setFirstResponderIfNecessary]
22 UIKit                          0x18b53365c -[UITextInteractionAssistant(UITextInteractionAssistant_Internal) oneFingerTap:]
23 UIKit                          0x18b8ef330 _UIGestureRecognizerSendTargetActions
24 UIKit                          0x18b518b5c _UIGestureRecognizerSendActions
25 UIKit                          0x18b3a685c -[UIGestureRecognizer _updateGestureWithEvent:buttonEvent:]
26 UIKit                          0x18b8f070c ___UIGestureRecognizerUpdate_block_invoke898
27 UIKit                          0x18b3658b8 _UIGestureRecognizerRemoveObjectsFromArrayAndApplyBlocks
28 UIKit                          0x18b36263c _UIGestureRecognizerUpdate
29 UIKit                          0x18b3a46cc -[UIWindow _sendGesturesForEvent:]
30 UIKit                          0x18b3a3cc8 -[UIWindow sendEvent:]
31 UIKit                          0x18b3744a4 -[UIApplication sendEvent:]
32 UIKit                          0x18b37276c _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue
33 CoreFoundation                 0x185d98544 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__
34 CoreFoundation                 0x185d97fd8 __CFRunLoopDoSources0
35 CoreFoundation                 0x185d95cd8 __CFRunLoopRun
36 CoreFoundation                 0x185cc4ca0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific
37 GraphicsServices               0x190d2c088 GSEventRunModal
38 UIKit                          0x18b3dcffc UIApplicationMain
39 MyApp                          0x1000599ec main (main.m:14)
40 libdyld.dylib                  0x19b1728b8 start
```

Comment: Can you use TapGesture event in view controller for resign keyboard?

Comment: Yes, I am using TapGesture to resign the keyboard already

Comment: I have face same error many times.

Comment: Error becuase of you use tapGesture and Alertview with Textfiled.

Comment: So You need to remove tap Gesture for resign keyboard and Use Texfiled Method : -(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField

Answer (score 1):

I got the same crash before.And the reason was the view controller has released and the UITextField.delegate is not setting nil,was a Dangling pointer issue. And i set UITextField.delegate = nil in dealloc method of the view controller,bug fixed.

Comment: Thank you for the update. I kept nil in dealloc. But I am unable to confirm whether it get fixed or not. Because this crash is not getting with my internal testing to confirm whether this fix made crash-free about it or not. Can you give some light in producing it and confirm the fix?

Comment: @SrinivasG Were you able to confirm that setting the delegate to nil fixes the problem? If not, have you figured out the correct solution?

Comment: @SrinivasG can you confirm if it fixed your problem?

Comment: So far, we couldn't reproduce. I will update here if the crash is reported again

Comment: Fabric reported the crash again even though we set delegate as nil